# android click animation blocks onItemClick

Tags: android, gridview, android-listview, background, onitemclicklistener

I have implemented etsy's staggred grid in my android app.

i have a layout:

```
<RelativeLayout 
...
android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
android:clickable="true">

    ...

</RelativeLayout>
```

and code:

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
        Log.i(TAG, "onItemClick");
    }
});
```

turns out , when i drop the two lines in XML , the onItemClick gets fired with no background animation and when i leave the two lines as is, the animation shows but the onItemClick doesn't get fired.

I suppose that the click on `RelativeLayout` blocks the click on it's parent which is the `AdapterView` container , and then the `StaggeredGrid` doesn't register it.

How can I have both click event and background animation ?

Answer (score 0):

Just add the click listener to your `RelativeLayout`. So in your getView() function in your adapter, set the click listener to your item.

So you want to do something like this:

```
... class ViewHolder {
    ...
    ViewGroup viewRoot;
    ...
}
...
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder vh;
    ...
    vh.viewRoot = convertView.findViewById(R.id.id_of_relative_layout);
    ...
    vh.viewRoot.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick() {
            // Do stuff
            Log.i(TAG, "Item clicked on item with position: " + position);
        }
    });
    ...
}
```

Comment: but i need to do something with the info in the `ArrayList` of the `GridView` , so i need the `position` input

Comment: You can get the position from the argument passed in to getview